# How to ignore a test in C# when CurrentEnv is Prod

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nunit-3.0

have created a ProdIgnoreAttribute which extends from IgnoreAttribute. And I have assigned this attribute to certain tests which I want to run in DEV/QA but not in PROD.

> ApplyToTest(Test test) method is not being called in this case. How to resolve this?

```
public class ProdIgnoreAttribute : IgnoreAttribute
{
private string IgnoreReason { get; }

public ProdIgnoreAttribute(string reason) : base(reason) 
{
    IgnoreReason = reason;
}

public new void ApplyToTest(Test test)
{
    if (test.RunState == RunState.NotRunnable)
        return;

    if (StaticInfoHelper.VrCurrentEnv == (int)RunEnv.PROD)
    {
        test.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
        test.Properties.Set("_SKIPREASON", (object)IgnoreReason);
    }
    else
    {
        base.ApplyToTest(test);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about extending Attribute rather than IgnoreAttribute?

```
public class ProdIgnoreAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
{
  public void BeforeTest(TestDetails details)
  {
    bool ignore = StaticInfoHelper.VrCurrentEnv == (int)RunEnv.PROD;
    if (ignore)
      Assert.Ignore("Test ignored during Prod runs");
  }

  //stub out rest of interface
}
```

If you want a custom ignore message you could make a ProdIgnoreAttribute constructor that accepts a string.  You'd then use the attribute on tests like:  [ProdIgnore("ignored because xyz")]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tweaked the class to extend and implement from : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest and then used overriden method:

    ApplyToTest(Test test) and ignored the tests in prod.
    if (StaticInfoHelper.VrCurrentEnv == (int)RunEnv.PROD)
            {
                test.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
                test.Properties.Set("_SKIPREASON", ProdIgnoreReason);
            }
            else
            {
                test.RunState = RunState.Runnable;
            }